# How to pass a space as value in @CsvSource

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5, junit-jupiter

Cannot figure out the syntax to pass a space as a value in jupiter's `@CsvSource`

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
                " ,lastName"
})
void test(String firstName, String lastName) {
...
}
```

but `firstName` is null and not a space character. Is it doable at all with this annotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to surround the space with single quotation marks as shown below:

```
@CsvSource({
                "' ',lastName"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try one of this solutions:

1. You can escape space value using double quotes, like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
    "\" \",lastName"
})
void test(String firstName, String lastName) {
    // Your test logic
}
```

2. You can use an escape sequence for a space, such as `\s`. This should ensure that a space character is passed as the value for firstName, like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
    "\\s,lastName"
})
void test(String firstName, String lastName) {
     // Your test logic
}
```

Comment: I tried the first approach, but it didn't work. firstName contained both quotes and space between them after that.

Comment: You can try with signle quotes `' '` in the first approach.

Comment: Can you try the second soltuion, if it works fine, pls?

Comment: Unfortunately not. firstName contains `\s`